# Difference between data() and string()

Tags: xquery, xquery-3.0

What is the practical difference between the data() function and the string() function in Xquery? It seems they both return the same results when I use them. Can someone give me a simple example of how they are different?

```
let $dataset := 
  <data-set cool="rad">
    <!--- This is a comment -->
    <pages cool2="rad2" more="i guess">
      <page>
        <title>Puppy</title>
        <content>Puppies are great!</content>        
      </page>
      <page>
        <title>Dogs</title>
        <content>Dogs are grown up!</content>        
      </page>
      <page>
        <title>Puppy</title>
        <content>Puppies are great!</content>        
      </page>
    </pages>
  </data-set>

return $dataset/string()
(: data() returns the same thing as string() :)
(: return $dataset/data() :)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`string()` will always return a string, whereas `data()` returns the "typed value". Most of the time this will be `xs:string`; however, it can also be `xs:untypedAtomic` or any other atomic type (typically defined in a schema).

There are some unintuitive cases too. For example, getting `data()` on a document node will return the string value of the node, but as an `xs:untypedAtomic`. As a general rule, if you want a string, use `string()` not `data()`.

See the spec for all the details: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-data.

And this section has a very good explanation of the difference between typed- and string-data http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#typed-string-relationships.

Comment: See also this discussion - http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell#comment-407618423.  The whole article is useful if you're unsure about text() too.